# Correct way to switch cameras on android

Tags: android, camera, xamarin.android

I have inherited a piece of Android code that switches camera by using `camera.Open(int);`

When this is compiled, I am getting an error that`Open(int)` has been deprecated (I have warnings as error switched on), yet can't find any examples on how to open the front facing camera without using `Open(int)`.

What is the correct way to switch cameras to avoid this deprecation error?